# Is there a way to ask for the deletion of an answered duplicate question a posteriori?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, quality-improvement

Yesterday I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445137/how-to-have-factory-function-return-a-non-copyable-object) about some specific piece of code I was working on but the semantic "essence" of the question had to do with (sorry for the details) the way the return statement and the move-semantic interplays in C++11.

A posteriori, I should have read some [existing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391946/returning-non-copyable-non-movable-object-with-explicit-constructor) more carefully and found my answer there. I am pretty sure my question don't add value to the site (although I am not the only one to judge - my post wasn't upvoted -- well it just got). My question wasn't flagged as duplicate and someone provided a valid answer I accepted. Now, I cannot delete this question anymore.

What do you think should be done in such case ? Is there a way to ask for a question deletion a posteriori or at least flag it as duplicate ?

Comment: That is possible.  Done.

Comment: Couldn't you simply flag as duplicate itself? (and accept the duplicate after you refreshed the page)